# How do I add SSL with Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I uploaded my angular 4 project to Firebase Hosting and it works well on Firebase's domain. However, when I connect it to my custom domain it should use SSL but as you can see on the image below, SSL is not active.

[image: SSL Error]

How do I set up SSL with Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Firebase Hosting will only serve traffic over SSL. However it may take a bit of time before your custom domain propagates. During this time, you'll see the "not secure" warning and may even see a different domain name when you click it.

If the problem persists and you're not able/willing to share the domain name here, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Comment: Mine took over 4 hours. Give it time!

Comment: Mine took over 24 hours, but less than 72 hours. (Didn't check during the gap.)

Comment: As I said: reach out to Firebase support for personalized help in troubleshooting. There's nothing anyone here can do about it, without additional details (which would actually be a different question).